# Why do I get nvarchar value null to a data type in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting an error in SQL Server:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Null' to data type int.

In my employee table I have:

```
ID Int, 
Name nvarchar(50),
Gender nvarchar(10), 
Salary nvarchar(50), 
DepartmentId nvarchar(50)
```

Nulls are allowed only for `DepartmentId`.

In my Department table I have:

```
Id int, 
Department Name nvarchar(50),
Location nvarchar(50), 
DepartmentHeead nvarchar(50)
```

None of them allow nulls.

I am trying to join the tables as so:

```
Select Name, Gender, Salary, DepartmentName
From Employee
JOIN Department ON Employee.DepartmentId = Department.Id
```

That's when I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Null' to data type int.

I am not understanding the error here. My goal is to join the `DepartmentName` column with the `Employee` table.

Comment: Some employees don't have a department?

Comment: "Gender nvarchar(10), " - really! It gets better! "Salary nvarchar(50),"

Answer (score 1):

The DepartmentId column in the Employee table should have been defined as an INT. Because it is the Foreign Key of the ID column in the Department table - which is defined as an INT.

Your employee table should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    ID Int, 
    Name nvarchar(50),
    Gender nvarchar(10), 
    Salary nvarchar(50), 
    DepartmentId INT
)
```

The DepartmentId column needs to be an INT, because it joins to the ID column of the Department table which is defined as an INT.

It seems like you may have some string values in the DepartmentId column with the word 'null'. These are not nulls but strings. You will need to convert them to NULLs first, using something like this:

```
update employee set departmentid = null where lower(departmentid) like '%null%'
```

Comment: Oh I can't believe I did not catch that. So now when I try to change the Data type to Int I get a error and cant save the int. How do I do that graphically or in a query? I get Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Null' to data type int.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: I use SQL 2008. I get Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Null' to data type int. The statement has been terminated. This is using a query

Comment: wait, it sound like some of the values have the string 'null'

Comment: So only the DepartmentID has a null but when I try to uncheck it in sql 2008 It does not let.

Comment: they are not null values, but strings with the word 'null' - not the same thing. You can update that column to convert the string 'null' to proper null values, I have updated the answer with this query. If that works, and assuming that there are only numbers remaining, you should be able to alter the column to an INT through SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Omg man thank you. Do you know if it is good practice to add a Foreign Key to DepartmentId?

Comment: DepartmentId is (should be) a Foreign Key, it is a Foreign Key of the Id column of Department. The id column of the Department table is (should be) a Primary Key.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're storing a foreign key reference to another table (in this case, `DepartmentId` on the Employee table to the `Id` field on the Department table), they need to be of the same data type. If you don't have the foreign key reference defined, you should. It will help ensure referential integrity and prevent errors like this.
2. When storing `null` in a field, you need to be sure you're storing an actual `null` value rather than a string containing "Null" (which is what it looks like you're doing in this case). It's that conversion that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be like this:

```
SELECT Name, Gender, Salary, DepartmentName
FROM Employee
JOIN Department ON Employee.DepartmentId = CONVER(nvarchar(50), Department.Id)
```

And if your goal is really *join the DepartmentName column with the Employee table*:

```
SELECT Name, Gender, Salary, DepartmentName
FROM Employee
JOIN Department ON Employee.DepartmentId = Department.DepartmentName
```